# "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream for a computer vision xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Android.App.Result.Ok && data != null)  
        {  
            mBitMap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");  
            imageView.SetImageBitmap(mBitMap);  
            byte[] bitmapData;  
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())  
            {  
                mBitMap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);  
                bitmapData = stream.ToArray();  
            }  
            content = new ByteArrayContent(bitmapData);  
        }  
}
```

Comment: At the very least add on which line the exception occurs. A full stack trace is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add a comment, but this is too long. I think you have a few problems:

Actually, fundamentally your code doesn’t make sense. It looks like you are trying to pass a Bitmap via an Intent, just to convert it back to a byte array. Just pass the byte array in the Intent.

There are other problems with how you tried to do this even ignoring the above.

`mBitMap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");`  should not work at all. In fact I’m very surprised it doesn’t throw a runtime exception here. You can’t just add a Bitmap to an Intent so although Intent.Extras.Get returns an object, it should always throw an exception if you just try to cast it to a Bitmap. You also can’t just cast a byte array to a Bitmap. If you want to pass a Bitmap via an Intent, you should first convert it to a byte array, then add that to your intent. On the other side, get the byte array from the Intent and convert it to a Bitmap.

There is also a limit to the amount of data that can be passed via an intent. Google do not specify how much data it can hold as it's dependent on a number of factors (like heap size) but assume it is less than 500kb. The rule is, keep the amount of data you pass small.   If the bitmap is small, like an icon, then you will be ok, but if its too large you will get an exception.

MemoryStream will also have a data limit based on a number of factors including allocated heap size, so again, that can easily be an issue if you are dealing with large amounts of data. If you are using streams with large data sets, either use a class that implements buffering automatically or implement it yourself.

Lastly, beware passing Bitmaps around anyway. They take up a lot of memory and you have to be very careful not to create memory leaks through references. Remember to dispose of the bitmaps and remove all references to them (or use Weak References), on both sides of the intent once you have finished with them.

If the Bitmap is large, persistent, or you have more than one, you should consider writing it to the file system then retrieving it, though again, remember to dispose of any bitmaps you have and remove all references to them.